# Conditionally execute nested block restore_to_point_in_time

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to execute the restore_to_point_in_time block conditionally depending on the flag restore set as true or false.

- Question 1: how can i achieve this? I tried using for_each with dynamic, didnt work.
- Question 2: on using restore_time argument I am getting error as unexpected argument.

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "rds_mysql" {
  .. ....
  
restore_to_point_in_time {
  source_cluster_identifier         = var.source_cluster_identifier
  restore_type                      = var.restore_type
  restore_time                      = var.restore_time
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html) is the way to do it:

```
resource "aws_rds_cluster" "rds_mysql" {
  .. ....
  
dynamic "restore_to_point_in_time" {

   for_each = var.restore == true ? [1] : []

   content {
    source_cluster_identifier         = var.source_cluster_identifier
    restore_type                      = var.restore_type
    restore_time                      = var.restore_time
    }
  }
}
```